# Is there a way to compute a a Variance Swap Fair Strike directly from the SVI implied volatility parametrization?

Tags: quantitative-finance, volatility

Suppose I have fitted Gatheral's SVI parametrization to an equity implied volatility surface. From these fitted parameters, is there a a method to directly compute the fair strike of a variance swap from the SVI parameters without having to compute a replicating strip of options?